# Applying a Patch (created through Patch Design View) over previous Quick patches already installed

Tags: installshield, patch

For one of our product, we deployed two quick patches to update few files. Recently, to overcome an issue in the product we needed to include a new custom action in the patch. As adding a custom action is not possible in case of quick patch we had to create a full patch instead (through Patch Design View in Install Sheild).

Now the problem we are facing is, though it shows installation of new patch is successful, updates of the new patch do not get reflected in the target system. My question, is it possible to apply a full patch over a system that has quick patches already installed.

Vinit

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes, you can create such a patch. In practice, since it requires exactly recreating the changes applied in the quick patches in your new upgraded image, very few people try to do this. My recommendation is to just create a major upgrade. But if you truly require a minor upgrade patch, you should be able to finagle it.